# Checking if a json response row exists or not in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

Here is my json response

> {u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'rows': [{u'f': [{u'v': u'1'}, {u'v': u'1607'}, {u'v': u'coriolanus'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'1'}, {u'v': u'1596'}, {u'v': u'kingjohn'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'1'}, {u'v': u'1599'}, {u'v': u'kinghenryv'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'1'}, {u'v': u'1600'}, {u'v': u'merrywivesofwindsor'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'1'}, {u'v': u'1602'}, {u'v': u'troilusandcressida'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'1'}, {u'v': u'1592'}, {u'v': u'comedyoferrors'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'2'}, {u'v': u'1590'}, {u'v': u'3kinghenryvi'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'2'}, {u'v': u'1612'}, {u'v': u'kinghenryviii'}]}, {u'f': [{u'v': u'2'}, {u'v': u'1598'}, {u'v': u'2kinghenryiv'}]}], u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'1039435439624', u'jobId': u'job_ffb30cfb23674f88aa5cb497e358ec05'}, u'jobComplete': True, u'totalRows': u'9', u'schema': {u'fields': [{u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'sum_for_the', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'corpus_date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'f0_', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}]}}

I loop through this using the below python code

```
resp = []
for row in listReply['rows']:
  for key,dict_list in row.iteritems():
    count = dict_list[0]
    year = dict_list[1]
    corpus = dict_list[2]
    resp.append({'count': count['v'],'year':year['v'],'corpus':corpus['v']})
```

How to check if this `listReply['rows']` exists or not as in case of a json response such as below

> {u'totalRows': u'0', u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'jobComplete': True, u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'1039435439624', u'jobId': u'job_8efc645852c34515bcff4ab3969772fd'}, u'schema': {u'fields': [{u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'sum_for_the', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'corpus_date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'f0_', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}]}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for row in listReply.get('rows', []):
```

If listReply has a key "rows", this will iterate over the corresponding value. If the key doesn't exist, the default is returned, which should be an empty list in this case so `for` will not complain since it is iterable.

Another way is to test for the key before entering the for loop.

```
if 'rows' in listReply:
    for row in listReply['rows']:
        ...
```

Comment: but in second method what is row before entering the for loop

Comment: @jade, sorry that was a typo. That's why I prefer the former - less chances to make mistakes :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
if key in aDict:
  # Operations
```

To test for the existence of an entry in a python dictionary.  If it'll be an empty list you can also do this:

```
if key in aDict and aDict[key]:
  # Operations
```

Because evaluation is left-to-right, if the key is missing the second check will not be performed, but if it is present and empty, the second check will skip the operations.

Comment: u mean if row in listReply and listReply['rows']

Comment: @jade - Yes, `if 'rows' in listReply`.  Also, `listReply.get('rows', [])` as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a key exists in a `dict` use the `in` keyword.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> 1 in d
16: False
>>> d[1] = 1
>>> 1 in d
17: True
>>> d
18: {1: 1}
```

so to use your example

```
>>> d = {u'totalRows': u'0', u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'jobComplete': True, u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'1039435439624', u'jobId': u'job_8efc645852c34515bcff4ab3969772fd'}, u'schema': {u'fields': [{u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'sum_for_the', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'corpus_date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'f0_', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}]}}
>>> 'rows' in d
19: False
```